# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'merlin.tradelogic' and problems around pyhv and deap modules

Tags: python

I have inherited some code that I am trying to execute unsuccessfully. For background I have needed to move the code from an old environment to a new one.  The Python code is launched from a folder called mktdata.out via a shell script called ./launch.sh.  This seems to be working okay.  However the following error is returned to the terminal soon after the ./launch is executed:

```
[user@localhost mktdata.out]$ ./launch.sh 
[user@localhost mktdata.out]$ /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/deap/tools/_hypervolume/pyhv.py:33: ImportWarning: Falling back to the python version of hypervolume module. Expect this to be very slow.
  "module. Expect this to be very slow.", ImportWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/deap/tools/_hypervolume/pyhv.py:33: ImportWarning: Falling back to the python version of hypervolume module. Expect this to be very slow.
  "module. Expect this to be very slow.", ImportWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "strats/merlin.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "strats/merlin/tradeopt.py", line 11, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'merlin.tradelogic'
```

I think the output is telling me that a module called a script called tradelogic is missing from merlin. However I have looked at the old environment from which all the code was moved from and it's set up the same way as the new environment. So I am unsure as to what I need to do in order to get this code working.

I'm unsure if its related but there is also an error in the terminal output around deap and pyhv.py.

### Edit

Please see below for the file structure under strats:

```
├── dao
│   ├── cythonlib
│   │   ├── cyrandom.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── fin
│   │   ├── algorithms.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── pnl.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
│   │   ├── port_opt.pyc
│   │   └── stats.pyc
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── iotools
│   │   ├── blbmktdata.pyc
│   │   ├── blpwrapper.py.bak
│   │   ├── blpwrapper.pyc
│   │   ├── datamodel.pyc
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── pair
│   │   ├── adfvalues.pyc
│   │   ├── cointegration.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── pairid.pyc
│   │   └── spread.pyc
│   ├── stock
│   │   ├── corpactions.pyc
│   │   ├── filter.pyc
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   └── utils
│       ├── concreteid.pyc
│       ├── config.pyc
│       ├── functools.pyc
│       ├── __init__.pyc
│       ├── itertools.pyc
│       ├── roll.pyc
│       └── rw.pyc
├── merlin
│   ├── cmdopt.pyc
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── instrument.pyc
│   ├── mktdata.pyc
│   ├── overview.pyc
│   ├── pair.pyc
│   ├── portfolio.pyc
│   ├── stratconfig.pyc
│   ├── tradega.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
│   ├── tradelogic.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
│   ├── tradeopt.pyc
│   ├── utils.pyc
│   ├── var.pyc
│   └── wrtconfig.pyc
├── merlin.pyc
└── merlin.sh
```

Comment: if there is a file `merlin/tradelogic` `merlin.py` could be taking that context away, and no `tradelogic` class/var/function exist in that file, thus the error

Comment: What does the directory structure look like under `strats/`?

Comment: #C.Nivs I've added the file structure to the question body